# Are there names for the sections in a monster stat block?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, terminology, books

The Monster Manual have tapered horizontal rules that separate sections of the monster stat block (after the monster type, before and after the ability scores, and after the challenge rating).

Are there any official (or else, widely-accepted) names for the sections between these rules?

I wrote a little HTML/CSS for stat blocks, and would like the markup to be as semantic and standard as possible.

Comment: Have you considered sending a tweet to a dev?

Comment: Be aware that formatting a stat block to look like a WotC stat block may breach their copyright/trade mark.

Comment: Thanks @DaleM. If I were to distribute, I'd do it by the terms of the Dungeon Masters Guild. Right now, this is just for personal use. It's not *exclusively* about writing semantic HTML - it could be useful while collaborating with other content creators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only sections that have names but aren't explicitly labeled are Ability Scores and "Special Traits," which is between Challenge and Reactions/Actions. The other sections aren't explicitly named. They're described on pages 6-9 of the Monster Manual.

That appears to be it as far as the core books are concerned, though if Wizards refers to them outside of the books as anything in particular, I'll amend this answer.

Comment: Informally, I had to name the "unnamed" sections for a web project and named them **Identity** (name, size, type, alignment), **Basic Characteristics** (AC, HP, speed), **Advanced Characteristics** (saves, skills, senses, languages, immunities, vulnerabilities, resistances, challenge), then all the rest. That isn't a widely accepted standard, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks @Polisurgist - do you have in *on authority* that the sections are officially unnamed? Understood, in the Monster Manual *Statistics* section, only the individual items, and not the sections, are described - but that doesn't mean folks at WOTC didn't refer to them by names. The names just might not have made it into the book. (And it looks like you guess it: I wrote a little HTML/CSS for stat blocks, and would like the markup to be as semantic and standard as possible. I'll follow your example if nothing more official turns up.)

Comment: I don't have anything on whether they're referred to by name outside of the core books, sorry. Or at least I don't have any citations that they're specifically _not_ named outside of the MM.